# How to add type cast to MethodInvocation using Eclipse JDT AST?

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I am trying to add type cast on a MethodInvocation node. For example,

```
Foo bar = anExpression.methodName();
```

will be changed to

```
Foo bar = (Foo)anExpression.methodName();
```

How to do this?

Comment: As you say "refactor" are you familiar with `ASTRewrite` for the mechanics of creating changes?

Comment: The link shows how to perform modifications on AST: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26396675/add-annotation-to-a-method-from-an-eclipse-plugin/26421273#26421273. Similar logic can be used for your case.